# Magically Living Furniture Template?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am GM'ing a group and they have encountered some living furniture, animated by their powerful wizard master.

I'd like to look at some monsters like this so I can begin to think about the living furniture's skills, levels, abilities, CR, etc.

Are there any monsters in the pathfinder books that are either living furniture or would be helpful to look at here?

Comment: Are you looking for intelligence here? Because zombie-level intelligence is covered by Sdjz's answer, but it might be a bit more complex if you'd like them to actually have personalities.

Comment: The immediate concern was deciding on a bluff skill bonus, so yea, intelligence was a factor.  I decided to play it by ear. The creature is a talking door designed by the wizard to be a sort of gate-keeper and greeter, so I decided that it would have a +12 to bluff, diplomacy, and sense motive. Not sure if that was excessive or not, but it's what I went with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for seems to fit [animated objects](https://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Animated%20Object). Note that this includes all sorts of objects of different sizes, from tiny to colossal (and a chair is given in the example table):

> An animated object is not simply one monster, but a whole category. The stats presented here are for a Medium animated object. (...) Creating an animated object of a different size than Medium can be done simply by adjusting the object’s size (and thus adjusting its Strength, Dexterity, natural armor bonus, and size modifier to attack and AC as detailed on page 296) and Hit Dice.

There is also the spell [animate objects](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Animate%20Objects) that is one way of creating these (though notably it is not a wizard spell) and the [craft construct feat](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Craft%20Construct), perhaps an easier option for a powerful wizard.